# React Router multiple params in url not navigating to component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to make routers with more then 1 param in url but for some reason it does not work. It changes the url but not rendering the component.

this is my App.js:

```
import routes from './fuse-configs/routesConfig';
import history from '@history';

const jss = create({
    ...jssPreset(),
    plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, jssExtend(), rtl()],
    insertionPoint: document.getElementById('jss-insertion-point')
});

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider
            value={{
                routes
            }}
        >
            <StylesProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
                        <Auth>
                            <Router history={history}>
                                <FuseAuthorization>
                                    <FuseTheme>
                                        <FuseLayout />
                                    </FuseTheme>
                                </FuseAuthorization>
                            </Router>
                        </Auth>
                    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                </Provider>
            </StylesProvider>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

declaring urls:

```
const MachinesConfig = {
    settings: {
        layout: {
            config: {}
        }
    },
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/machines',
            component: Machines
        },
        {
            path: '/machines/hi',
            component: Preferences
        },

    ]
};

export default MachinesConfig;
```

```
const routeConfigs = [MachinesConfig];

const routes = [
    ...FuseUtils.generateRoutesFromConfigs(routeConfigs),
    {
        path: '/',
        component: () => <Redirect to="/machines" />
    }
];


export default routes;
```

The routes in the App.js are coming from the above routes and are printed correctly. However, when I click on the row, it changes the url to the correct path but nothing is shown.

If I change the path string itself from '/machines/hi' to '/somethingElse' it works and renders the component. For some reason it cannot accept the 2 params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Please use `exact` prop for your `Route`. Like this (where you are using the Route tag):

```
<Route path="" component="" exact />
```

If you want to make it dynamic/optional then you can declare it in your routes file:
e.g.

```
routes: [
    // ….
    {
        path: '/machines',
        component: Preferences,
        exact: true // true|false to control this
    },
    // ….
]
```

**Old Answer:**

If your are talking in terms of "number" of parameters then you need to specifically mention the routes structure, so that each route is mapped correctly.

```
    routes: [
        // for main route
        {
            path: '/machines',
            component: Machines
        },
        // for route with 1 param
        {
            path: '/machines/:id',
            component: Preferences
        },
        // for route with 2 params
        {
            path: '/machines/:id/:name',
            component: DesiredComponent
        },
    ]
```

Otherwise, simply this will do:

```
{
  path: '/machines/:id',
  component: Preferences
},
```

This will make your parameter dynamic and hence will render your component properly.

As a side note, if you are already on the route `/machines/:id` and the param value is changed, then please note component will not re-render completely, instead its lifecycle method will be called (`componentDidUpdate` or `useEffect`, depending).

Comment: If I only leave '/machines/:id' it tries to go straight to that path with id=undefined. For the time being I changed the path to be '/machine/:id? without the "s" at the end which works, but still not sure why it acts that way

Comment: Oh I see, then you are missing the `exact` prop from your Route. I am updating the answer please check.

Comment: actually your routes are being read from top to bottom so if `/machines` is declared and in next line `/machines/:id` is declared, until and unless you provide `exact` prop, if you write `/machine/abc/xyz`, your app will only read the base url and immediately redirect to that component i.e `/machines`.